# How to configure RPi to work as wifi access point that uses a Burp as a proxy?

Tags: proxy, iptables, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I am attempting to use a Raspberry Pi Model B+ as a WiFi access point with the IP address of 192.168.0.1. This access point should redirect all HTTP and HTTPS traffic to a different machine with the IP address of 192.168.0.29 on port 8080.

On 192.168.0.29, I am using Burp Proxy, that is listening for incoming connections. I've configured Burp with the option 'support invisible proxying'.

I have successfully set up the WiFi access point and am able to connect to it with various client machines. The Internet connection through the access point is also functioning properly.

I've used hostapd for setting up the wifi access point.

However, when I try to add the proxy configuration, the access point stops working. I can see that outgoing requests are going through my proxy on 192.168.0.29, but I am not receiving any responses on the proxy or on the client machines that are attempting to use the proxy.

I'm using the following configuration on my Pi:

```
sudo iptables-legacy -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables-legacy -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.29:8080

sudo iptables-legacy -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.29:8080
```

Burp is listening and the option 'support invisible proxying' is activated. However I don't see incoming responses only the outgoing requests.

This is the result of curl a request to https://webhook.site/

```
curl "https://webhook.site/213c00e4-5ec8-4c8d-a89a-34d542c6d81/network=PiAP" -v                                  [17/12/22 14:07:10]
*   Trying 46.4.105.116:443...
* Connected to webhook.site (46.4.105.116) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=PortSwigger; O=PortSwigger; OU=PortSwigger CA; CN=webhook.site
*  start date: Dec  3 13:00:10 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  3 13:00:10 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "webhook.site" matched cert's "webhook.site"
*  issuer: C=PortSwigger; ST=PortSwigger; L=PortSwigger; O=PortSwigger; OU=PortSwigger CA; CN=PortSwigger CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /213c00e4-5ec8-4c8d-a89a-34d542c6d81/network=PiAP HTTP/1.1
> Host: webhook.site
> User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
> Accept: */*
>
^C
```

I don't see the incoming request at https://webhook.site, what makes me wonder if the outgoing request actually work as expected.

This is the output of ifconfig:

```
ifconfig | grep 192                                                                                                                          
inet 192.168.0.29 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

And this is traceroute

```
traceroute google.com                                                                                                                        
traceroute to google.com (142.250.181.206), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  16.717 ms  4.513 ms  3.043 ms
 2  fritz.box (192.168.178.1)  3.710 ms  3.758 ms  3.484 ms
 3  ip1f11XXXX.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de (31.17.8X.XXX)  17.808 ms  35.506 ms  14.934 ms
 4  ip5886XXXX.static.kabel-deutschland.de (88.134.21X.XXX)  16.788 ms  14.614 ms  14.202 ms
 5  ip5886XXXX.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de (88.134.18X.XXX)  13.349 ms  13.917 ms  16.057 ms
 6  145.254.3.88 (145.254.3.88)  20.858 ms  18.649 ms  17.655 ms
 7  145.254.2.217 (145.254.2.217)  26.106 ms  16.028 ms  17.017 ms
 8  72.14.194.138 (72.14.194.138)  17.006 ms
```

Comment: I think you need to check out `TPROXY` (instead of `DNAT`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. As far as I understand the TPROXY options, this would only work if the Burp proxy would listen on the same machine as the access point. But in my case Burp is running on a different host and the traffic should be forwarded from the access point to the proxy.

Comment: If the traceroute is from the machine hosting burp, the requests sent by burp are going through the raspberry pi, and are themselves redirected to burp. You would need to add an exception for that machine in your iptables rules.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense and is what I'm observing on the proxy machine. I will try to figure out how to configure this exception. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: It turns out, that it is quite easier to use mitmproxy on the Raspberry Pi instead.